# How can I make a password system in Lua?

Tags: lua, password-protection

I am trying to make a password system, but for some reason, the code I want it to run when the password is correct doesn't run. I am not sure what is wrong, but I am looking for a solution to the problem, or another way to simply make a password system.
Here is what I have:

```
term.setTextColor( colors.red )
print("Password Required")
term.setTextColor( colors.cyan )
io.write("Password:")
local password = io.read()

while (password ~= "Password") do

    io.write("Incorrect")
    print("")
    io.write("Password:")
    password = io.read()
    if password=="Password" then
        sleep(.5)
        term.setTextColor( colors.green )
        print("Access Granted")
    end
end
```

Comment: It looks as if the code will not do anything (will not enter the while loop) if the user enters the password correctly on the first try

Comment: I'm not sure how I didn't notice this

Comment: I just noticed that I also forgot to add an if statement that detects if the password is correct the first time it is entered

Comment: Use `repeat until` loop instead of `while do`

Answer (score 1):

A basic solution to this problem can be achieved with a while loop.

```
term.setTextColor( colors.red )
print("Password Reqired")

while true do
    term.setTextColor(colors.cyan)
    io.write("Password:\t")
    term.setTextColor(colors.white)
    password = io.read()
    if password=="Password" then
        sleep(.5)
        term.setTextColor(colors.green)
        print("Access Granted")
        break
    else
        term.setTextColor(colors.red)
        print("Access Denied")
    end
end
```

This constantly repeats itself until the correctly answered password is supplied, in which break escapes the loop.

However, judging by your calls to 'term', I'm assuming you're using ComputerCraft. If so, you probably also want to prevent terminating, which can be done by overwriting the error function.

```
term.setTextColor( colors.red )
print("Password Reqired")


function error(txt)
    term.setTextColor(colors.red)
    print(txt)
end

while true do
    term.setTextColor(colors.cyan)
    io.write("Password:\t")
    term.setTextColor(colors.white)
    password = io.read()
    if password=="Password" then
        sleep(.5)
        term.setTextColor(colors.green)
        print("Access Granted")
        break
    else
        term.setTextColor(colors.red)
        print("Access Denied")
    end
end
```

But note, if someone can place a disk drive next to your computer, they can still get in.

Comment: correct, I am using Computercraft, in fact, its an online Computercraft emulator I found online. Heres a link if you would like to check it out: [https://gravlann.github.io/](https://gravlann.github.io/)

Comment: BTW Thanks, but I don't understand how someone could place a disk drive next to the computer and get it, The only explanation I could think of is that the person could place a disk drive and put a disk in the drive that has some programs that looks at the code in the program with this password system and gets the password and automatically types it in.